# Remove blank squares from waffle chart

Tags: r, charts, waffle-chart

I'm trying to make a waffle chart in R using the `waffle` package.  I don't have an even number of entries (49) and I get blank filler squares in my otherwise 
perfect chart (see purple/blue squares).

[image: Sample Chart]

Here is an example of the code:

```
library('waffle')
basedata <- c(11,38)
names(basedata) <- c("Awsome", "Not Awsome")
waffle(basedata, rows = 2)
```

Any idea how to remove the blank filler squares?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share some of your research?

Comment: the default color palette is `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, 'Set2')` where `n` is the number of unique colors, 2 in your case. if you try `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(2, 'Set2')`, you get a warning that this set requires at least 3 colors, no idea why. you can try `waffle::waffle(c(38, 11), 2, colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(2, 'Set2')[1:2])` or setting _two_ colors of your own. seems like the package authors should have foreseen such a basic case

Comment: Setting two colors of my own worked (but modifying the brewer colors did not).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
waffle(basedata, rows = 2, colors = c("blue", "green", "white"))
```

or if you want to match the colors to how they were, look up the color scheme at [Color Brewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=qualitative&scheme=Set3&n=4) and add the hex codes.

```
waffle(basedata, rows = 2, colors = c("#fb8072", "#8dd3c7", "white"))
```

Also, I assume the word "Awesome" isn't included in the real thing, but in case it is, be sure to add that extra "e" in there. :)

Comment: Worked great!  Thanks for the "awesome" help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to "white out" the fillers. It's a known weird behaviour of `waffle`.

Just pass **two** colors:

```
waffle(basedata, rows = 2, colors = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image: Awesome plot]